# Missing require not throwing ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just deployed a Node app that had a missing require statement which resulted in the app crashing, however on my local development machine no `ReferenceError: <symbol> is not defined` is ever thrown so it's not caught by my test cases.

What could cause this and what can I do to insure that the ReferenceErrors are thrown in my development environment when a require is missing from code?

Comment: Figure out what's wrong with your deployment? You shouldn't be removing `require` statements when shipping to production.

Comment: it depends when the required package is executed. Within a function? or on app start ?

Comment: @Mike C: This was new code where the require statement was never there-- I wasn't removing them.  The deployment was to a development server, so fortunately no harm was done.

Comment: @HolySamosa If the require statement was never there, why wouldn't it throw on your local machine? You ought to be running the code on your local machine in an environment that is at least very, very close to what you'll be running it on later.

Comment: @Yerken: The required module was executed in a function.  Thanks!

Comment: @Mike C: Exactly-- I'm trying to understand that exact thing.  This is a new project and I'm presently setting up Jenkins to manage builds and tests on the hosting platform where hopefully this type of thing would get caught.  Just scratching my head on why my dev system wouldn't throw.  Thanks!